# Consecutive Comparisons

Tags: syntax, comparison

When I try to do compound comparisons the use of the braces don't seem to work correctly, as tried below?

```
\documentclass [letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin {document}
\def\TrnsATypeA {Sale and Mortgage}
\def\MortPolAAmtB {350,000}
\ifdefstring{\TransATypeA}{Sale and Mortgage}
{\ifdef {\MortPolAAmtB}}
{\input {J:/TITLE_COMMITMENT/A1-0001c.tex}}\par %Second Loan
{}
{}

\end {document}
```

Comment: i find the closing brace at the end of `{\ifdef {\MortPolAAmtB}}` suspicious.

Comment: `\TransATypeA` is not defined did you intend  `\TrnsATypeA` ?

Comment: Daivd, Yes it should be \def\transATypeA just a fat finger mistake.

Comment: but isn't that the whole issue as if it is undefined it takes the false branch and if you use the defined command it takes the true branch

Comment: please edit the question so the example is an example of your problem and say what output you expect just saying "don't seem to work correctly" doesn't allow anyone to help, as it will work but your expectation is presumably different but it is hard to guess what you expect if you do not say.

Comment: The intend of the above example is to input the file if both of the test are True. As defiined in the example code, it give a undefined control sequence.

Comment: The intent if this code is to input the file if both test are true. With the example code I get a Undefined Control Sequence.